# Find the shortest curve that crosses given discs

Tags: approximation, calculus-of-variations

Let $D_{n}$ be a set of discs. Where $n=1,2,...,n'$.

Each disc is defined as follows $D_{n}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:(x-a_{n})^2+(y-b_{n})^2\le C^2\}$

Where $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ are some sets of real numbers. $C$ is constant.

> Find the curve, such has the shorthest length among all curves that crosses all discs.

I know it is a general question, but i would like to know how to apply calculus of variations in order to solve this problem.

Regards.

Comment: With "cross you mean run through the center? May the disks overlap?

Comment: No, it may run through the center or near the center. The curve should have at least one common point with each disc. Yes, the discs may overlap.